# How to print multiple elements (div) & it values - Selenium WebDriver in java

Tags: java, selenium

1). How can I get all  element value in array/list?

2). And How I click by value of the  element?

```
<div class="Choice" style="margin-top: -483px;>
<div class="ChoiceEntry Choice_1"> 5</div>
<div class="ChoiceEntry Choice_3"> 10</div>
<div class="ChoiceEntry Choice_2"> 20</div>
<div class="ChoiceEntry Choice_4"> 50</div>
<div class="ChoiceEntry Choice_7"> 75</div>
<div>...</div>
</div>

  private static String choiceXPATH = 
".//div[@class='Choice']//div[contains(@class,'ChoiceEntry')]";
```

//this getSize() method work Correctly.!

```
public int getSize() {
    waitUntilXXXButtonIsVisible();
    List<WebElement> count = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(XPATH));
    return count.size();
}
```

How can I get all element value in array/list?

```
public String getAllListValue(){
    List<WebElement> list = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
    return list.toString();;
}
```

I tought, i will get String array like "5,10,20,50,75". :-)

My second question is How can we click by div element value or div class Name(ChoiceEntry Choice_{index} )?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you will probably have to override the toString method if you want the output using your code.

The simpler approach to achieve what you are trying to do is.

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
    Iterator<WebElement> iterator = list.iterator();

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        WebElement element = iterator.next();
        values.add(element.getText());
    }

    System.out.println(values.toString());
```

Comment: thanks, my result look like this.   
[10, 5, 100, 75, , , , , , , , , ], there should be 13 elements. I don't know why some elements are not show in the array list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> listOfDivs = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
```

As per your code if above line gives desired list size then use below code to fetch values

```
for(WebElement element : listOfDivs)
{
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Comment: thanks, my result look like this. [10, 5, 100, 75, , , , , , , , , ], there should be 13 elements. I don't know why some elements are not show in the array list.

Comment: Try to print list.size(). If if it returns 13 elements then it will print 13 Values

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet for getting the list of values:

```
public List<String>  getAllListValues(){
    List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class^='ChoiceEntry Choice_']"));
    List<String> valuesOfChoices = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(WebElement item : items){
        valuesOfChoices.add(item.getText());
    }

    return valuesOfChoices;
}
```

Code snippet for clicking on a selective choice:

```
//position of the choice is not 0-based
public void getAllListValues(int positionOfTheChoice){
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("class='ChoiceEntry Choice_"+positionOfTheChoice+"'")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it soon. 
by the way, when we have css class like "ChoiceEntry Choice xxx", I tought we better use with xpath! :-)

Comment: xpath is not a better solution and it should be avoided  if possible :)